# Access BIOS/UEFI menu setting via uefi shell

Tags: bios, uefi

I´d like to read/alter some BIOS/UEFI menu settings via a uefi shell script.

For example I´d like to change the 'CSM Support' setting (Enabled/Disabled).

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the uefi variables (not shell variables) before and after you change the 'CSM Support' setting, maybe this setting is stored in one of the uefi variables, you can then edit this variable from the shell or a simple shell app.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I had already checked the ´dmpstore´ command output. But as I haven´t found anything named so I gave up. But your suggestion to double check it by changing settings and compare the dmpstore output made me find the corresponding parts. But there is a problem: I can only run the ´set´ cmd to set Shell enviroment variables. The ´setvar´ cmd needed to set UEFI variables does not run at normal shell level (only at Debug 1 level, which I don´t know how to access this).
BTW: Generally this approach might be a bit risky as one might change the variable in a unsupported way, right?

Comment: You are right, setting config values in this way is risky and implementation dependant (like many other things in uefi), but i do not think that there is any other way to do this from the shell.
If you can disable secure boot, you can write your own shell app to set a variable, i think that there is a sample for this in the edk2 repo.
Dmpstore has a parameter to load variables from a file, i never tried it but maybe it can load a single variable.

Comment: Thansk. With `dmpstore -l filename varname` it´s possible to load the variable values from a file. Using `dmpstore varname` I can check that the values have been changed. I´d assume that with a reset the changes should have effect. But the problem is that the changes were lost after reset (again checking with dmpstore)...

Comment: Maybe the variable doesn't have the non volatile flag set, you should see the flags in the dmpstore output.

Comment: The non volatile flag is set. At the moment I´m trying to change ConOut. That has the flags: NV+RT+BS (before and after changing the values).