# UEFI Shell: Change value of variable persistently (nonvolatile)

Tags: uefi

I wrote a UEFI-App to change uefi variables (calling gRT->SetVariable(..)). Although I change a non-volatile variable, the changes are not persistent through reset.

How can I make the changes persistently?

With the UEFI-App I´m able to change the value of the variable I choose. With `dmpstore variablename` I can verify that the value of the variable has been changed correctly (and that it has the 'NV' flag). But after reset the old value is recovered.

I use a uefiversion 2.4 and uefishellsupport 3.

The background of this question is this question: [Access BIOS/UEFI menu setting via uefi shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756635/access-bios-uefi-menu-setting-via-uefi-shell).
I´d like to change variables like ConOut, ConIn and other variables which I can change in the BIOS menu settings.

BTW: Setting environment variables via the `set` uefi shell command, does make persistent changes. I don´t understand why the changes of UEFI variables aren´t persistent...

Comment: Which UEFI variables are you trying to persistently change?

Comment: I added that to my question.

Comment: You should study platform initialization process. You can't just save anything you want to ConOut and expect it to persist after reboot

Answer (score 1):

Not all changes to UEFI global variables persist across a reboot.

In the case of `CONIN`, `CONOUT` and `ERROUT`, the following paragraph from section 3.6 of the UEFI specification applies:

"The ConInDev, ConOutDev, and ErrOutDev variables each contain an
EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL descriptor that defines all the possible default devices to use onboot. These variables are volatile, and are set dynamically on every boot. ConIn, ConOut, and ErrOut are always proper subsets of ConInDev, ConOutDev, and ErrOutDev."

Comment: Thanks. OK, so ConOut etc depend on ConOutDev and that is volatile!?! Any suggestion about how to manipulate the "set dynamically on every boot" process?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL.SetEnv()` to set UEFI Shell environment variables.

> This function changes the current value of the specified environment variable.
>   If the environment variable exists and the Value is an empty string, then the
>   environment variable is deleted. If the environment variable exists and the
>   Value is not an empty string, then the value of the environment variable is
>   changed. If the environment variable does not exist and the Value is an empty
>   string, there is no action. If the environment variable does not exist and the
>   Value is a non-empty string, then the environment variable is created and
>   assigned the specified value.

See the [UEFI Shell Specification](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_2_2.pdf) for more details

Comment: Thanks, but I think that´s not what I´m looking for. I want to change the UEFI variables (which I can get and alter via  `setvar` or `dmpstore`), not the environment variables. (or do they relate in any way?)

Comment: I know. Sorry, might be that the "btw" comment is confusing. I just wanted to say that the environment variables does keept their (changed) value after reboot. But the UEFI variable does not (and I want to have persistent changes for them too). -> I added that to my question.

Comment: I see. Do UEFI vars changes persist if you edit them with `setvar` command? Are those some vendor-specific or genaral variables? Can you add them to you question?

Comment: No, editing them with setvar gives the same (non-persisting) result. That was why I tried to do so via the  `gRT->SetVariable(..)` to see if there is any difference in behavior. But it isn´t. I added the variables/background to the question.